# Kotlin android - Change value of 'app:' attribute

Tags: android, kotlin, attributes, shadow

I want to change the `app:sl_shadowColor` value programmatically in Kotlin:

```
<com.dd.ShadowLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:sl_shadowColor="#33000000"
                    app:sl_cornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:sl_dx="1dp"
                    app:sl_dy="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
                        android:letterSpacing="0"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Wähle ein Datum"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:theme="@style/Theme.ButtonWhite"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"/>

                </com.dd.ShadowLayout>
```

When my Button is disabled, the shadow is still visible so I want to change the value of `sl_shadowColor` to `#00000000` when my Button is disabled. How do I access `sl_shadowColor` programmatically?
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You should look into the documentation of the `com.dd.ShadowLayout`, or you can check the code and you can find any method that will allow you to set that property value at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is custom attribute defined to bind the action to the Button. Look for the method for `sl_shadowColor` with `@BindAdapter` annotation in your project. Apply it only for enabled state of the `Button`. For details read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter).

```
@BindingAdapter("sl_shadowColor")
fun setShadowColor(view: Button, shadowColor: Color?)
{
    if(view.enabled){ ... }
}
```